# Reducing code repetition for Showing Dialogs Android?

Tags: android

The app requires showing the same dialog from various places in the app.

How do we create a function that helps creating DRY code.

Example of Opening the `Dialog`:

```
LocationDialogFragment lf = new LocationDialogFragment();
              Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
              bundle.putString(Constants.CURRENT_NAME, name);
              bundle.putLong(Constants.CURRENT_ID, id);
              lf.setArguments(bundle);
              lf.show(getFragmentManager(), "TAG");
```

This is done in many activities and fragments in my app. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to create a DialogHelper class with a static method, which you can call from anywhere.

Pass it the parameters which are related to the context, like the fragmentManager, like this:

```
public class DialogHelper{

    public static LocationDialogFragment createAndShowLocationDialogFragment(long id, String name, FragmentManager fragmentManager, Bundle bundle){

        LocationDialogFragment lf = new LocationDialogFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(Constants.CURRENT_NAME, name);
        bundle.putLong(Constants.CURRENT_ID, id);
        lf.setArguments(bundle);
        lf.show(fragmentManager, "TAG");

        return lf;
    }

}
```

This way you can call it from wherever you'd like where you have access to a `FragmentManager`:

```
LocationDialogFragment currentDialog = DialogHelper.createAndShowLocationDialogFragment(5, "DialogName", getFragmentManager(), bundle);
```

If you don't want to show the dialog instantly, just to create it, you can remove the `show` method from the static method, and that way you don't need to pass the `FragmentManager` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

extend a Dialog, override and set everything in show method for example

Answer (score 0):

Create an Helper class where you can put static methods and do like this:

```
//In the Helper class
public static void createLocationDialog(FragmentActivity fa, String name, String id,String tag, Bundle args){
    LocationDialogFragment lf = new LocationDialogFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(Constants.CURRENT_NAME, name);
    bundle.putLong(Constants.CURRENT_ID, id);
    lf.setArguments(args);
    lf.show(fa.getFragmentManager(), tag);
}

// in the fragments:
createLocationDialog(getActivity(), thename, theid, thetag, theargs)
```

Comment: I almost posted the same :) But if you return the dialogFragment itself, you can alter the arguments, and have a reference for it later on for any possible changes.

Comment: That's right, indeed. but I didn't want to change to much his code so he could easily find his path. Should I edit it?

Answer (score 0):

1. make a static newInstance(params) method in your DialogFragments
2. instantitate the arguments bundle there
3. do ListFragmentDialog.newInstance(params).show(); where needed